# How can I clean this text?

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, text, request

How do I clean this text?

```
input = "Ti as\u00edn y\u00e9 as\u00edn k\u00f3 t\u00f3 \u1e63\u1eb9nu gb\u1ecd\u1ecdr\u1ecd; ti \u1ecd\u0300k\u00f9n y\u00e9 \u1ecd\u0300k\u00f9n k\u00f3 t\u00f3 fi igba \u1eb9s\u1eb9\u0300 r\u00ecn."
```

I expect to see `Ti asín yé asín kó tó ṣẹnu gbọọrọ; ti ọ̀kùn yé ọ̀kùn kó tó fi igba ẹsẹ̀ rìn.`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Those are the exact same string, just written different ways. `input == output` evaluates to `True` for me.

Comment: That's the ascii-printable representation of a unicode string. Internally, it's as you expect. `\uxxxx` is the ascii encoding for unicode characters. If you display it using a unicode-capable display (such as having the python serve it to a browser), it'll look as you expect.